# firebase SDK error- Cant find variable admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

When i am using the code below, i am getting an error :- cant find variable  admin

```
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail('svd@gmail.com')

      .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        //console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
        alert(userRecord.toJSON());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
      })
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the code you've provided. It's wherever `admin` is or isn't defined or imported.

Comment: You tagged this as a question about React.  Are you trying to use the Admin SDK in a client environment?  You should know that you can't do this.  It only works in server environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this and tell me whether this works for you or not. I'm also not sure whether it's a fetch issue or DB issue from your firebase JSON data.

As far as this admin variable is concerned, it looks like it is a firebase instance, make sure that you initialize your firebase in your project correctly. Follow this link and add it to your project, then import or initialize it in your particular class where you want to fetch the details.
[Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Thinking that you might have stored some of the data. Doing code like this would work :

```
firebase.auth().getUserByEmail('svd@gmail.com')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
     /* check the data is it coming in your console or you can simply put it inside the alert() */
     console.log(responseJSon);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
});
```

**Note:** Before implementing that make sure you have initialized the `admin` variable in your code, else it won't be able to perform an operation on null variable or non-defined variable. Ensure that as well.

Comment: It looks like you're defining admin in Java style rather than in JavaScript style.  Pretty sure that's not going to work.

Comment: I have proper edits in my code. Thanks, @DougStevenson for letting me know, I too thought it's not gonna work for that. :)